# My class method is not called, and I think it's related to my directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After I restructured some files, I'm getting an error. When I call

```
@batch << Formatter.get(@fields)
```

it returns `@fields`.  When I try to use debugger to go into the `Formatter.get` method, I see that it is skipped.

I have a directory structure like:

- lib/

  - klass/

    - formatter.rb

      formatter/

      - formatter.rb

        foo_formatter.rb

        bar_formatter.rb

lib/klass/formatter.rb contains:

```
require 'formatter/formatter'
require 'formatter/foo_formatter'
require 'formatter/bar_formatter'
module Klass
  class Formatter
  end
end
```

And lib/klass/formatter/formatter.rb contains:

```
module Klass
    class Formatter

        attr_accessor :fields

        def self.get fields
            case fields[:field_id]
            when "foo"; FooFormatter.new fields
            when "bar"; BarFormatter.new fields
            end
         end
```

lib/klass/formatter/foo_formatter.rb contains:

```
module Klass
    class FooFormatter < Formatter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the namespace of lib/klass/formatter/formatter.rb so that it reads

```
module Klass::Formatter
    class Formatter

        attr_accessor :fields

        def self.get fields
            case fields[:field_id]
            when "foo"; FooFormatter.new fields
            when "bar"; BarFormatter.new fields
            end
         end
```

Comment: I did that both in lib/klass/formatter.rb and lib/klass/formatter/formatter.rb and now get this error: undefined method `get' for Klass::Formatter:Module.

Comment: Just had to update the other child classes to use Klass::Formatter.  Thanks!